# How to handle return values through two functions

Tags: c, recursion, return

I have a programme that calls a function, which in turn calls a recursive function.

How do you pass the result of the recursive function back to the main programme via the middle function?

Currently it will return either found **or** didn't find depending on how I structure the middle function. In this instance it would return 'found' every time. I know that the binary search function is working although there may be an error in what it is returning to the search function.

Call from main programme:

```
if (search(value, array, size))
{
    printf("\nFound!\n\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\nDidn't find.\n\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Search function:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if(binary_search(value, values, ((n - n) + 1), n))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Recursive function:

```
bool binary_search (int key, int array[], int min, int max)  
{   
    if (max < min)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int midpoint = (min + max)/2;

    // {
    if (array[midpoint] > key)
    {
        return binary_search (key, array, min, midpoint-1);
    }

    else if (array[midpoint] < key)
    {
        return binary_search (key, array, midpoint+1, max);
    }

    else if (array[midpoint] == key)
    { 
        return midpoint;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
// }
}
```

Comment: You can, you know, *return* the value. And indent the code please.

Comment: You should not be returning -1 in a bool.

Comment: How about `return binary_search(value, values, ((n - n) + 1), n)` ?

Comment: You can not return midpoint in bool, until the midpoint has Boolean values!

Comment: Your bool binary_search() method is wrong, as it has return type which does not match the return type of the method. 

Such as : return -1 and return midpoint.

Comment: You also have one extra curly bracket after int midpoint = (min + max)/2;

Which is unnecessary.

Comment: @G Spencer What is the purpose to have two functions instead of one recursive function?

Comment: @G Spencer And why the initial minimum index is equal to 1?

Comment: @G Spencer In any case the recursive function is wrong. :)

Comment: @this  It is funny that this exists but that does not yet exist.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. The reason I have two search functions is that the initial one has to receive that input and I am not permitted to amend it. The recursive function requires min & max input so I therefore think I need the separate function to accept the amended input

Comment: @G Spencer  Why does the recursive function require min and max? It can have the same parameters as the first function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `binary_search` function is not returning a boolean in all instances.

In the place where you `return -1` you should instead `return false`.  Similarly, where you `return midpoint` you should instead `return true`.

Edit:

As mentioned in Vlad's comment, you should be starting your search at 0 instead of 1, otherwise you won't find anything at the start of the list.

Comment: That's not a very useful search if it only says "yes, it's here somewhere". Better to fix it to return `int`, which is either found index or -1.

Comment: @dbush His recursive function is wrong apart from the problem of the return value.